# Как изменить цвет списка файлов в Linux

Tags: bash, linux

Как сменить цвет выводимого списка файлов в Linux? Командой ls я вывожу список файлов, все файлы темно-синего цвета, что не очень хорошо читается. Помогите мне пожалуйста изменить цвет.

Или где найти файл, куда можно писать настройки (.bashrc). У меня нет своего хостинга, пользуюсь услугами. Поэтому доступ к основным настройкам сервера не имею.

Comment: [Вот здесь](http://leolik.blogspot.ru/2008/03/lscolors-ubuntu.html)  для убунты расписано. 

А вообще см. `info coreutils 'dircolors invocation'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls --color=autocd ~echo "alias ls='ls --color=auto'" >> ./.bashrc || echo "alias ls='ls --color=auto'" > ./.bashrc
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, что мне это даст?

Comment: Первая команда покажет, как это будет выглядеть (раскраска). Вторая и третья сделает "эффект раскрашивания" постоянным.

Answer (score 4):

```
ls --color
```

Что бы постоянно не писать **--color**, добавьте в **~/.bashrc** следующее:

```
alias ls="ls --color"
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая переменная LS_COLORS. Гуглите  на тему "настройка LS_COLORS" и найдете много разного. Но это вообще то вопрос на  руткод.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls -lAXh --color=always|less -R
```

попробуй так

Answer (score 0):

В вашей домашней директории лежит файлик `.bashrc`

в нем ищете переменную `PS1`. Ее настройки отвечают за цветовую схему.
У меня стоит так:
 `PS1="\t \[[\e[0;32m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\h\[\e[m\] \[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[m\]]\[\e[0;31m\] ..\$\[\e[m\]\[\e[0;37m\] "`